# ASP.NET MVC database can not access

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc

I download a open source MVC project and I can not run it. The author mentioned in the memo that I should change the database owner to myself. But I don't know how to do it. And I can not see the database in the SQL server Object explorer.

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred accessing the database. 
>   This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file.
>
> See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the failure.

The error pointed here

```
public override TEntity ReadOne(ISpecification<TEntity> spec) {
    return this.set.Where(spec.IsSatisfied).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

`web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="mvcForum.DataProvider.MainDB" connectionString="Data Source=SERVERNAMEorSERVERNAME\INSTANCE;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User ID=USER;password=PASSWORD"/>
    <!--add name="mvcForum.DataProvider.MainDB" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQL2008r2Express;Initial Catalog=mvcforum;User ID=test;password=test;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <!--<add name="User.MongoDB" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/mvcforum" />-->
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Can you include the code that shows how you are instantiating your `DbContext` derived class?

Comment: (1) Do you have a version of SQL version (in the first place) - e.g. express? (2) What db requirement/s does the mvc project have? e.g. restore a backup db or just access to a db (thereby implying that you must have some SQL instance on your machine)?

Comment: To my surprise I get the same error even when my sql server database is in stopped state. Very decieving error message :P. My connection string was alright.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change the connection string, the simplest way is to open server explorer in visual studio then add new connection, after creating connection to your database, copy and paste connectionstring from properties window

Comment: Thank you so much! I just opened server explorer, when I tried to create new Sql server database, the "server name" I got nothing, and when I clicked OK, I got pop up window says" a network-related error... The server was not found or not accessible." I checked my computer service, it only got one service started with SQL, called "SQL Server VSS Writer",do I miss some components?

Comment: In that dialog you should enter name of sql server instance, try setting it as `.` (it means local computer default instance), and set authetication mode to windows authentication. 
Did you installed sql server? for being sure go to start>programs> sql server>Configuration tools>sql configuration manager, and run it, then see if you have any running instance of sql or not.